# how to Cover import statement in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

how  to covered unit test on import module .  tried "transformIgnorePatterns" and "coveragePathIgnorePatterns" to ignore  it but its not working

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Jest configuration, in the variable collectCoverageFrom, use a negative entry:

```
collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/**/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.interface.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.module.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/__mock__/*',
],
```